# Ripcord is not working in live server

Tags: xml-rpc, odoo-8

I'm using ripcord to connect php to odoo server via webservice api. The library is working perfectly in local, but in server is not working and is getting a lot of time to work.

Any idea if it's modules php or other thing?

Comment: please can paste youre issue over hear